# ScriptManager run script immediately

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an update panel load a user control, and the goal here is to have a specific JavaScript function called when this occurred.  I was thinking this would be done through the Script Manager, though this does not need to be the case if there's an html alternative.

The flow is basically the following:

- User clicks button
- Update panel loads control
- Javascript function is called

Many thanks

I've already tried `RegisterStartupScript(..)`, though i may have made a syntactical mistake

```
if (show)
{ 
    string scriptId = String.Format("{0}:script", ++uniquePopupId);
    string scriptTag = String.Format("showPopup({0},{1});", Width, Height);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), scriptId, scriptTag, true);
}
```

Solution:

```
if (show)
{ 
    string scriptId = String.Format("{0}:script", ++uniquePopupId);
    string scriptTag = String.Format("showPopup({0},{1});", Width, Height);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updPanelChildControl, updPanelChildControl.GetType(), scriptId, scriptTag, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(myControlInstance, 
                                    typeof(MyControl),
                                     "key",
                                     "my javascript string here", 
                                     true);
```

Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx).

Comment: I've tried something similiar to this already unless you see something wrong with what i've done.

Comment: Ahh, i'd been using RegisterStartupScript wrong, thanks for the documentation.