# Does C# has any methods to execute Javascript function when button is pressed?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

My situation is following:

I have `OnTextChanged` event handler on my aspx page, what calls `TextChanged()` method from code-behind. Now, I need to run a javascript script at the end of that `TextChanged()` method. How can I do this? Does `ScriptManager` have any methods what will execute the scripts only then when I change text in my textbox?

I might be a duplicate question, but I couldnt find information whether the scriptmanager has any methods that will run script immediately after registering it.

The actual problem is that, I need to put a script at the end of TextChanged() method and the script will just have to set focus from one html element to another.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526313/scriptmanager-run-script-immediately

Comment: Thats not recommended. Use jQuery/Javascript to handle onchange unless you really need to, server side Text_Changed should be avoided.

Comment: @fahadash why? Who said one must use AJAX? It's totally legit and not a bad practice to have a form submitted when text is changed.

Comment: Many of the scenarios don't need postback, People have been found using this for turning the textbox red when email address is incorrect while that could easily be done with 1 line js code.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply send the required JavaScript in the code behind itself:

```
public void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "text_changed", "alert('Text was changed');", true);
}
```

This will show the alert only after `TextChanged()` is executed in the code behind.

If you're not inside a Page instance (e.g. static library) have such code, assuming you're in the context of a Page and not in some HTTP Module or something like that.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page, typeof(Page), "text_changed", "alert('Text was changed');", true);
```

Comment: Cant you tell me whats the difference between ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
and ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript, cuz i cant use this.ClientScript... ('...Pagename' does not contain a definition for clientscript) - i have reference to system.web.ui

Comment: @Marek, I think his code shows an instance of a ScriptManager which is called "ClientScript". Declare a ScriptManager in your class, and call it in your TextChanged eventhandler.

Answer (score 1):

write below code in text changed function where you want to execute script. And put your java script function name in place where i bold text

```
**>ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Javascript","JavaScriptFunctionName()", true);**
```